# Open a WPF Application from a Windows Button click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Is it possible to open a WPF Application from a C# Windows button click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch it like any other applicaiton. Use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method. If you need more control, you can create an instance of the Process class (`Process process = new Process()`)and adjust its properties. You can see the Process class's [members here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.  You should look into [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).